# D3 height attribute using a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to use a function to use d3.scale() for my height and I keep getting an error:

```
var heightScale = function(d) {
    console.log(d);
    return d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([d['clicks'], 0])
        .range([270, 20])
};
var bars = vis.selectAll("rect")
    .data(clicks)
    .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("width", 30)
        .attr("height", function(d) {
            return heightScale(d)})
        .attr("fill", "red")
        .attr("x", function(d,i){return i * 60})
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (max_width + 20) + ", 20)");
```

Error: Invalid value for  attribute height="function i(n){return o(n)}"

Can you spot anything wrong with this?

Comment: The `heightScale` function returns a function, which d3 is attempting to assign to "height".  Of course a function isn't a valid height.  Did you mean `.attr("height", function(d) { return heightScale(d)() })`.  Of course that looks fishy to me, usually the scale is set for the whole visualization, not bar by bar...

Comment: Ahhh, ok thanks!  So if I set the scale to the whole viz I can just use the raw numbers for the height?

Comment: See this classic [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304).  `var heightScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);` and then `.attr("height", function(d) { return height - heightScale(d.clicks); });`